# Bit representation of characters C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

Here's my program for bit representation of characters. But I don't know does it show me right or wrong representation? There are suspicious units (red colored).

[image]

Can you explain me what's this (if it's right) or what's wrong with my code if these units should not be. Thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

struct byte {
   unsigned int a:1;
   unsigned int b:1;
   unsigned int c:1;
   unsigned int d:1;
   unsigned int e:1;
   unsigned int f:1;
   unsigned int g:1;                   
   unsigned int h:1;
};

union SYMBOL {                              
    char letter;                    
    struct byte bitfields;
};

int main() {                                                              
    union SYMBOL ch; 
    cout << "Enter your char: ";
    while(true) { 

        ch.letter = getchar();
        if(ch.letter == '\n')  break; 

        cout << "You typed: " << ch.letter << endl;
        cout << "Bite form = ";
        cout << ch.bitfields.h;
        cout << ch.bitfields.g;
        cout << ch.bitfields.f;
        cout << ch.bitfields.e;
        cout << ch.bitfields.d;
        cout << ch.bitfields.c;
        cout << ch.bitfields.b;
        cout << ch.bitfields.a;
        cout << endl << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code is correct, so it reduces to a request for resources (here, the ASCII character value table)

Comment: @Useless: The poster _believes_ their is a bug, that may bring it back into on-topic.

Comment: By the way, the computer term is normally spelled "byte" instead of "bite"

Comment: @Useless I am guessing the OP expected a,b,c,... to be 1,2,3,... in binary, or something along those lines.

Comment: @MooingDuck OP got a result, didn't know what the result _ought_ to be, and asked if it was a bug - I'm not sure that's the same. IDK, maybe this will end up a useful resource for others who don't know how characters are encoded, but it's very narrow for that purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table to understand the output you're getting:

[image]

- `a` has the decimal value of 97, and 97 is 01100001 in binary
- `b` has the decimal value of 98, and 97 is 01100010 in binary

and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Bit fields are not portable. The biggest problem is that you don't know in which order the bits will be assigned to the individual bit fields, but you don't even know actually whether the struct will have 1, 2 or any other number of bytes.

I'd recommend using unsigned char (because you don't know whether char is signed or unsigned), and using code like (ch & 0x80) != 0, (ch & 0x40) != 0 etc.

Comment: Good point - just because you get the proper results doesn't mean the code is good.

Comment: And since `char` is not guaranteed to have exactly 8 bits, you don't even really know how many bit fields you would need.